# Change karaf (4.1.0) console colors back to normal (white)

Tags: colors, console, apache-karaf

I've installed Karaf 4.1.0 and after opening the console, I've experienced that the commands were disappearing when I was typing them. After inspecting carefully, I've noticed, that their color changed to dark blue, which is for me almost indistinguishable from black background from the distance I sit from my monitor.

Is it possible to revert those colors settings and get back all commmands simply in visible white? It's very uncomfortable to type something you can't see...

Comment: this depends on your local shell settings ... just change those for the terminal.

Comment: @AchimNierbeck how it could depend on my shell settings when in karaf 4.0.8 all was normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

> $KARAF_HOME/etc/shell.init.script

add following command:

> setopt disable-highlighter

then restart **karaf**.

Comment: This option was added in version 4.1.1. It seems that new colouring annoyed enough people so that they've made them optional.

Comment: I am using varsion 4.1.1 and 4.1.2 and this option is not present

Answer (score 2):

The colors can be configured via property `HIGHLIGHTER_COLORS` as documented for the [Apache Felix Gogo command line shell](https://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-gogo.html) used within Karaf.

For instance assign

```
HIGHLIGHTER_COLORS = "fu=32;1:bf=31;1"
```

within the Karaf shell for bright green *functions* `fu=32` and increased red *bad functions* `bf=31;1` to gain improved readability on a black terminal background.

The color settings can be persisted to be enabled on each Karaf start via adding the above configuration line to the

```
karaf/etc/shell.init.script
```

You can use any [Ansi Escape Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) for configuring the shell color.

This works for us on Apache Karaf `4.1.2` and we are happy (again) now with the new coloring feature :-)